# Wireshark make error: undefined reference to symbol 'g_module_name'

Tags: wireshark

I'm trying to compile wireshark-P2P-1.7.0 but it fails showing the following error:

/usr/bin/ld: gtk/libui.a(libui_a-plugins_dlg.o): undefined reference to symbol 'g_module_name'

//usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [wireshark] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sniffer/Desktop/P2P_install/Sigma_Sniffer-P2P-Ubuntu_v8.1.0/wireshark-P2P-1.7.0'

make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sniffer/Desktop/P2P_install/Sigma_Sniffer-P2P-Ubuntu_v8.1.0/wireshark-P2P-1.7.0'

make: *** [all] Error 2

---

I'm not sure if it requires special libraries to run on a 64bit processor since this version of wireshark is 32 bit.

I cannot use a standard version of wireshark or download it from anywhere else. I have to use this one because is specially configure to make WFA tests.

Thank you!!

Oscar.

Answer (score 0):

The only way a *source code* version of Wireshark would "[be] 32 bit" would be if somebody had added code to it that assumed that `long` or pointer data types were 32-bit; *no* code in the Wireshark source from wireshark.org is "32 bit" or "64 bit", it's all portable (and the Wireshark build infrastructure builds and tests both 32-bit and 64-bit versions).

What it *does* need is a version of GLib that includes `g_module_name()`, and you need to be linking with GLib (Wireshark uses it).